# file_get_contents no caching?

Tags: php, image, caching, file-get-contents

I'm using file_get_contents() to load a dynamic image from an external website.

The problem is that the image has been updated on the remote website but my script is still displaying the old image. I assume the server cache the image somewhere but how can i force the server to clear the cache and use the updated image when getting the file with file_get_contents ?

On my local machine, i had to do CTRL+F5 to force refresh on the image.

I also tryed to add no cache header to my script, but it didn't work:

```
    $image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path));
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
    header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT"); // Date dans le passé
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
exit();
```

Comment: Can you post the `URL` of the image ?

Comment: But you actually set the headers not to expire AFTER you get the file!?

Comment: Also see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36555

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP or Apache seems to be caching files read via file\_get\_contents or include (unwanted behaviour)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616427/php-or-apache-seems-to-be-caching-files-read-via-file-get-contents-or-include-u)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your problem is that you're using *external* resource to load your file. Once it was loaded - there's no sense to send some headers to *your* client. Your image *already* been loaded (and that was cache from external resource).

However, there's easy trick to resolve an issue. Let's suppose you're using something like `http://domain.com/path/to/image` in your `$path`. Then just do:

```
$image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($path.'?'.mt_rand()));
```

-so idea is to add some random value to GET-request and prevent it from being cached.

Comment: The thing is - not with all paths `?` is applicable (obviously, in some cases it can break valid URI)

Comment: I never experienced that before. Got anything to share ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran imagine that your path to image is `http://domain.com/image.php?id=xxx`. Adding another `?` will break valid URI. So blind concatenation with `?` isn't good idea in common case (at least `$path` format need to be clarified)

Comment: I always find it better practice to use `time()`, since it's less expensive than `mt_rand()`.

Comment: `time()` will definitely fail when several incoming requests fit it one second.

Comment: We recently found out at my office that doing this when making requests to picasa was causing the page to not be found , 404.  Once we removed the get variable it worked fine.

Comment: I don't know why file_get_contents stored cache but sending a random variable each time you call it the issue solve. Thank you.