# file_get_contents give random older images from Facebook image profile

Tags: php, facebook, image, avatar

I have simple php script, for get image from Facebook and download user profile image to my server.

```
  $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$idUser.'/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false';
  $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
  $url = $data["data"]["url"];
  $path = $idUser.'.jpg';
  file_put_contents ($path, file_get_contents($url));
```

In my CMS site I try to open user profile page, where all time I execute that script, because I want to see actual user profile image. But when user change user profile image my script is do wrong. file_get_contents download old image, when I refresh page or new image randomly. What that mean? Where is error?

That still my answer [file_get_contents no caching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754935/file-get-contents-no-caching)

but not work for me(

**> UPDATE:**

Facebook wrong get me json link randomly

Comment: You may have an invalid path in file_put_contents. As is, your path will be '..12345.jpg', but I think you're expecting '../12345.jpg'.

Comment: I update post, i am wrong wrote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran your code locally and got the same problem. Something is getting cached along the line, so I added a cache buster to end of the URL, and it forces the new image.

```
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$idUser.'/picture?width=200&height=200&redirect=false&' . time();
```