# PHP fopen gives me old version of file

Tags: php, drupal, fopen

I am trying to get the newest version of Drupal in php. So I figured I could get the second line of https://www.drupal.org/CHANGELOG.txt, which when I go to the url reads: Drupal 7.41, 2015-10-21 - Perfect.

But if I do this:

```
<?php
  $fh = fopen('https://drupal.org/CHANGELOG.txt','r');
  while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    echo $line;
  }
  fclose($fh);
?>
```

Or this (to get the second line of the file):

```
<?php
  $newestFile = file("https://drupal.org/CHANGELOG.txt");
  $newestVersion = strstr($newestFile[1], ',', true);
  echo $newestVersion;
?>
```

The file I get starts like this: Drupal 7.39, 2015-08-19. It seems that it is an old version of the file. How is that possible?

Comment: PHP might be caching the file. Maybe try something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754935/file-get-contents-no-caching ?

Comment: That worked :) thanks

Comment: What version of PHP is this? The last time I checked, file wrappers did not implement caching - and if it were a transparent proxy in between then it must also be tinkering with your SSL.

Comment: And (interestingly) this file is served up with max-age=2628001, hence the cache is stale, and drupal presumably don't make changes more than once a month.

Comment: It is PHP 5.6.13.
I can see that the drupal 7.40 was released on Oct 14, 2015 so the 7.39 version must have been cached somewhere before that I guess?