# Laravel and Cloudfront: Image caching issue

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-5, intervention

If I load this image from Cloudfront into my browser it shows me the correct and latest version:

```
https://d8z37rm9cmbl3.cloudfront.net/1/groupings/extras/27/FS_27_0003.JPG
```

However, when I load it programmatically in my Laravel app from my Forge server, it shows an old cached version of the image (which in fact no longer exists on AWS). The call is exactly the same within the program and the app's URL is:

```
http://imagetester.artlookonline.com/img
```

The code for the procedure is very simple and uses Intervention Image (but not their cache):

```
public function serveDirectImage() {

    $img = Image::make('https://d8z37rm9cmbl3.cloudfront.net/1/groupings/extras/27/FS_27_0003.JPG');

    // create response and add encoded image data
    $response = Response::make($img->encode('jpg', 70));

    // set content-type etc header
    $response->header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
        ->header("Cache-control", "no-store");

    // output
    return $response;

}
```

Comment: My question is what I am doing wrong? Why does my app load an old cached version?

Comment: Try to download image with your own implementation and pass it to the ```make``` method, you can also use Guzzle library. As far as I saw make can accept a number of data types. This would be the fastest way to get around this issue.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "download image with your own implementation". Can you explain more please?

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/api/make check second example. If the issue persists, check this response https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21754935/file-get-contents-no-caching